# JSONP sintax error pulling data from behance api, missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, api, angularjs, jsonp, behance-api

First off, I'm using angular js. I get syntax error that says missing ; before statement inside my console when trying to run the following function:

```
app.factory('behanceData', function($http){

    var factory = {},
        baseURL = 'http://www.behance.net/v2/',
        user    = 'EnokMadrid',
        apiKey  = 'wXg9JwtvGepF60zwE9f0t20YN4TGKxYc';

    factory.myCallbackFunction = function(data){
        // returning from async callbacks is (generally) meaningless
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }

var url = baseURL + "users/" + user + "/projects?api_key=" + apiKey;
$http.jsonp(url);

return factory;

});
```

In the behance api documentation states that the API will respond with:

```
myCallbackFunction({
  ...
})
```

So thats what I'm calling the function. In the angular js documentation it states that JSON_CALLBACK needs to be used. So if I add the following at the end of my url: ' ?jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK '  or  ' &callback=myCallbackFunction '    ...I still get a bigger Network connection error.

What should I do to fix this issue? I'm completely fustrated and just want this code to work.